# Google translation services - xml invalid root element

Tags: xml

As I upload a language xml file for translation in Google Play Services for apk files I get the following error when I click the next button.

"Invalid root element at row# 3.

My xml starts with:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<rootElement>
    a lot of elements within the rootElement tag.
</rootElement>
```

How could it possibly be anything wrong with the root element for the xml file at row 3, since it is only a simple root element and nothing else?
I've tried:
 - renaming the root tag
 - removing all tabs within the root tags.

It says extactly:
"english.xml, rad 3: ogiltigt rotelement."
which translates to:
english.xml, row 3: invalid root element.

Thank you, any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on this [sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicNetworking/res/values/strings.html), shouldn't the root element be named `resources`?

Comment: "Invalid" in XML terms usually implies that the XML is well-formed but doesn't match the schema/DTD that the receiver expects - are you sure you've used the right element names, namespaces (if any), and just as importantly you _haven't_ included anything that is _not_ allowed by the particular application you're working with?

Comment: Thank you, it was supposed to be named resources. 
However now it casts another error: 
"english.xml: Det finns inga meddelanden i den här filen."
translated:
"english.xml": There are not any messages in this file."

Do you have any idea what they mean? That I should include some kind of messages for the translator before each tag possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is invalid. There is a missing "<".  It should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

It looks like you dropped a character.

EDIT
I fixed the firmatting in the question (added a leading space) but if the space between the first and second characters is really how you have it then it needs to be removed.

Comment: It was not that, that was just a typo for the question. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @user3561039 it's still typo'd - you've got a space between the `<` and the `?` of that XML declaration

Comment: That was only because you can't post <code it will not be visible in the question diagram, it made everything after the < invisible. Something related to html tagging I guess.

Comment: You can post code.. you only had 3 spaces and there needs to be 4. I fixed it.